# preferredCompactColumn is being passed as NavigationSplitViewColumn.sidebar but still seeing details page on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationsplitview, navigationsplitview

As we can see in the code preferredColumn is set to NavigationSplitViewColumn.sidebar but when I open this app in iPhone 15 pro preview the NavigationSplitViewColumn.detail is shown and then user have to click back button on top to get to sidebar view

[image]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selectedSidebarItem: String? = ""
    @State private var isExpanded: Bool = true
    @State private var preferredColumn = NavigationSplitViewColumn.sidebar


    private var toolbarTitle: String {
        switch selectedSidebarItem {
            case "UrlToSummaryView":
                return "URL to Summary"
            case "GenerateShortStoryView":
                return "Generate a Short Story"
            case "YoutubeVideoToSummaryView":
                return "Youtube Video to Summary"
            case "GenerateIdeasView":
                return "Generate Ideas"
            default:
                return ""
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView(preferredCompactColumn: $preferredColumn) {
            List(selection: $selectedSidebarItem) {
                DisclosureGroup("Tasks", isExpanded: $isExpanded) {
                    NavigationLink(value: "UrlToSummaryView") {
                        HStack {
                            Image(systemName: "link")
                            Text("URL to summary")
                        }
                    }
                    NavigationLink(value: "GenerateShortStoryView") {
                        HStack {
                            Image(systemName: "chart.bar.doc.horizontal")
                            Text("Generate a short story")
                        }
                    }
                    NavigationLink(value: "YoutubeVideoToSummaryView") {
                        HStack {
                            Image(systemName: "video")
                            Text("Youtube video to summary")
                        }
                    }
                    NavigationLink(value: "GenerateIdeasView") {
                        HStack {
                            Image(systemName: "brain.filled.head.profile")
                            Text("Generate ideas")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Butler")
        } content: {
            Text("Hello")
        } detail: {
            if let selectedSidebarItem {
                switch selectedSidebarItem {
                    case "UrlToSummaryView":
                        ToolbarWrapper(title: "URL to summary") {
                            UrlToSummaryView()
                        }
                    case "GenerateShortStoryView":
                        ToolbarWrapper(title: "Generate a Short Story") {
                            GenerateShortStoryView()
                        }
                    case "YoutubeVideoToSummaryView":
                        ToolbarWrapper(title: "Youtube Video to Summary") {
                            YoutubeVideoToSummaryView()
                        }
                    case "GenerateIdeasView":
                        ToolbarWrapper(title: "Generate Ideas") {
                            GenerateIdeasView()
                        }
                    default:
                        Button("Sidebar") {
                            preferredColumn = NavigationSplitViewColumn.content
                        }
                }
            } else {
                Text("")
            }
        }
        .navigationSplitViewStyle(.balanced)
    }
}
```

I am expecting the sidebar view to be seen in the iPhone by default.

Comment: What happens if you start with the landscape orientation?

Comment: Same behaviour. @ElTomato

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you may know, the `NavigationSplitView` cooperates with `List`, to navigate to the different columns, depending on the list selection.

What I suspect is happening here, is that the line

```
@State private var selectedSidebarItem: String? = ""
```

makes `NavigationSplitView` think something in the `List` is selected initially, and so shows the content column (the column with "Hello" is not the detail column!), ignoring the preference you set.

If you set `selectedSidebarItem` to nil initially, this counts as "nothing is selected in the list", and so the `NavigationSplitView` respects your preference.

```
@State private var selectedSidebarItem: String? = nil
```

Comment: Thanks @Sweeper it works. I am new swift so thanks for helping me out.