# NavigationSplitView - having a .sheet in the detail view breaks in compact/iPhone mode

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationsplitview

I'm trying to get a NavigationSplitView working where on the iPhone in compact/portrait mode when you go to the detail view there is a '.sheet' that is available only on that view, and when you navigate back it goes away.  I'm coming across a few issues and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

1 - preferredCompactColumn seems to be ignored at the start in my minimal reproducible sample, it always starts into the detail view.
*fixed* thanks to link provided by sweeper - set to nil

2 - the sheet initially appears over the sidebar view at first launch despite being attached to the detail view. I get an error message... "swiftui sheet Presenting view controller  from detached view controller is not supported, and may result in incorrect safe area insets and a corrupt root presentation. Make sure  is in the view controller hierarchy before presenting from it. Will become a hard exception in a future release."

[image: Bottom sheet showing in the sideview at launch]

Minimal Reproducible Code below.

```
import SwiftUI

// simple sidebar for testing
struct SideBarView: View {
    
    @State private var selectedInt: Int? = nil
    
    var body: some View {
        List(1...3, id: \.self, selection: $selectedInt) { int in
            NavigationLink("Row \(int)", value: int)
        }
    }
}

// Detail View with a permanent bottom sheet
struct DetailView: View {
    
    @State var sheetVisible: Bool = false
    
    // fill the space
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            Text("detail view")
            Spacer()
        }
        .onAppear(perform: {
            sheetVisible = true
        })
        .onDisappear(perform: {
            sheetVisible = false
        })
        // show a bottom sheet that is for this view
        // in this case I have dismiss disable but it seems to break regardless
        .sheet(isPresented: $sheetVisible) {
            Text("Bottom Sheet")
                .presentationDetents([.fraction(0.15), .medium, .large])
                .presentationDragIndicator(.visible)
                .interactiveDismissDisabled()
                .presentationBackgroundInteraction(
                    .enabled(upThrough: .medium)
                )
        }
        
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    // bug? - this seems to be ignored at the start.  Initial view is the detail
    @State private var preferredColumn = NavigationSplitViewColumn.sidebar
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView(
            preferredCompactColumn: $preferredColumn)
        {
            // simple sidebar
            SideBarView()
                .navigationTitle("Sidebar")
        } detail: {
            // bug? - this detail view has a sheet displayed when active
            // but it's causing issues with ehe split view and I'm not sure
            // what I've done wrong with the setup
            DetailView()
                .navigationTitle("Details")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For the `preferedCompactColumn` issue, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/78042492/5133585

Comment: Thank you :) by setting the selectedInt to nil this now reproduces the bug I see in my main app I'm working on.  With that change, the sheet shows up over the 'sidebar' when it shouldn't at the start and I get the error message mentioned in 3.  
The sheet should only show in the detail view.

'@State private var selectedInt: Int? = nil'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tthe sheet appears even in the sidebar, because apparently the detail view's `onAppear` is called as soon as the sidebar appears, even when the detail view hasn't appeared. I think this might not be intentional.

To work around this, I thought of a way where you would need to shift the ownership of `selectedInt` from `SideBarView` to `ContentView`. The idea is to let the detail view know about whether anything is selected in the sidebar.

```
struct SideBarView: View {
    
    @Binding var selectedInt: Int?
    
    var body: some View {
        List(1...3, id: \.self, selection: $selectedInt) { int in
            NavigationLink("Row \(int)", value: int)
        }
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    
    @State var sheetVisible: Bool = false
    
    let hasSelected: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            Text("detail view")
            Spacer()
        }
        .onChange(of: hasSelected, { oldValue, newValue in
            if !oldValue && newValue {
                sheetVisible = true
            }
        })
        .sheet(isPresented: $sheetVisible) {
            Text("Bottom Sheet")
                .presentationDetents([.fraction(0.15), .medium, .large])
                .presentationDragIndicator(.visible)
                .interactiveDismissDisabled()
                .presentationBackgroundInteraction(
                    .enabled(upThrough: .medium)
                )
        }
        
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selectedInt: Int?
    @State private var preferredColumn = NavigationSplitViewColumn.sidebar
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView(
            preferredCompactColumn: $preferredColumn)
        {
            SideBarView(selectedInt: $selectedInt)
                .navigationTitle("Sidebar")
        } detail: {
            DetailView(hasSelected: selectedInt != nil)
                .navigationTitle("Details")
        }
    }
}
```

`DetailView` now knows whether itself is presented by checking `hasSelected`. Only when `hasSelected` changes from false to true (this means the user tapped a row in the sidebar), does it set `sheetVisible = true`.

Comment: Yup, that's fixed it and I think I can use the same approach in my main app.  Thanks for the help.  Seems like a SwiftUI bug at the moment ?

Comment: @syp5w2qxe Yeah, I suspect it is a bug. `onAppear` shouldn't be called in this case.